# How was Ezra aware of this fact?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

**Be careful! Major spoilers ahead** if you have not seen the latest Rebels episode ***Twin Suns***[<sup>1</sup>](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Twin_Suns_(episode)).

During this episode

> Obi-Wan kills Darth Maul

and as a consequence Ezra says to his friends back at Chopper base:

> We won't be seeing Maul again.

This is of course true, but how could Ezra know this? He left Obi-Wan and Maul before the fight. Yes, he took his ship, but this does not mean that

> Maul could not leave the planet with another ship, given that he survived the fight with Obi-Wan.

Have I missed something obvious on screen?

Comment: Could he have assumed that Obi-Wan is not going to lose a fight with Maul? I don't need to see the "**Selena Gomez vs Mike Tyson**" title fight to know who's gonna win....

Comment: We don't know. Although I think it's safe to assume Obi went to the space port and picked up his animal thing.

Comment: @Valorum Why should he assume this? One of his reasons to come to Tatooine at first place, was that he believed Kenobi would need his help against Maul. This was of course a ridiculous misbelief by Ezra as the episode fortunately reminded us of how weak Ezra (and thus also Kanan) is compared to an experienced and powerful jedi like Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sub>Quite speculative, so maybe not a good answer. But in my opinion based on reasonable assumptions.</sub>

At the end of the episode, we see Obi-Wan watch Lars call Luke back to the house. In this scene he is riding his [Dewback](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dewback).

[image: Obi-Wan riding his Dewback]

However, in the scene just before Maul's death, Obi-Wan sends Ezra North on his Dewback as that is "his way home".

[image: Obi-Wan giving Ezra the Dewback]

From my understanding of the link between these two scenes. Obi-Wan went north to catch up with Ezra, led Ezra to Maul's ship and sent him on his way. In the process, informing him of Maul's death and Ezra freedom from his influence.

Comment: I think this nails it. Taking this Dewback into consideration, we have good reasons to assume that Obi-Wan and Ezra met off screen after Obi-Wan's fight against Maul.